# Compass CSS Sprites - Purpose of vertical layouts

Tags: css, sprite, compass-sass

[In this page here](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/sprite-layouts/), Compass gives allowance for 4 different types of layouts for sprites - vertical, horizontal, diagonal and smart.

It mentions that the smart layout is the most efficient use of space for a layout, which is very plain to see.

However, Compass *defaults* to using the vertical layout on Sprites! Why? And why even offer up different types of layouts? Is there any practical reason?

Comment: 1. How are we supposed to know? We didn't make that program. 2. This is opinion-based in any case.

Comment: @Doorknob I disagree. There may be obvious reasons for offering these options for CSS sprites and it's totally valid to ask when to use what type for what reason.

Comment: It's not an opinion question at all. An example answer I might not know about: 'Because vertical layouts are better for spacing icons apart, and we like to add trailing spaces because ...'. There's obviously a purpose. I am asking if someone knows what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One difference is the generated file size. 
Depending on the images that are combined to a sprite, it is advantageous to select the option which fits best the image space without much whitespace. This will result in a smaller image size than using one of the other options.

This may lead to use `smart` option most of the time. Google uses sprites of that style, too.
The smart sprites are most probably more cpu intensive to generate than simple horizontal or vertical sprites. I do not know if there are other reasons for selecting horizontal/vertical sprites over smart sprites.